# Is there any way to switch JSON files for the same script?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement dark mode on my web where I have the [particlesj](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) script and I need to modify the color of the particles for the light mode. Is there any way to switch between JSON files? Let's say particles.json and particles-light.json. Appreciate any help so much.

Comment: you can rerload the library on theme mode change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a sample using themes with tsParticles here: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/vYejMNr

You can have a single config with configured themes like in the sample above.

I'll show below more in details how to achieve it.

```js
    // the particles container, used for calling the loadTheme method
    let themeableContainer;

    document.getElementById("btnLight").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (themeableContainer) {
        // the theme name must be used when loading theme
        themeableContainer.loadTheme("light");
    }
    });

    document.getElementById("btnDark").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (themeableContainer) {
        // the theme name must be used when loading theme
        themeableContainer.loadTheme("dark");
    }
    });

    tsParticles.loadJSON("tsparticles", "particles.json").then((container) => {
    // assigning the loaded container
    themeableContainer = container;
    });
```

and the config looks like this

```json
    {
        "fpsLimit":60,
        "particles":{
            "move":{
                "bounce":false,
                "direction":"none",
                "enable":true,
                "outModes":"out",
                "random":false,
                "speed":2,
                "straight":false
            },
            "number":{
                "density":{
                    "enable":true,
                    "area":800
                },
                "value":80
            },
            "opacity":{
                "value":0.5
            },
            "shape":{
                "type":"circle"
            },
            "size":{
                "value":{
                    "min":1,
                    "max":5
                }
            }
        },
        "themes":[
            {
                "name":"light",
                "default":{
                    "value":true,
                    "mode":"light"
                },
                "options":{
                    "background":{
                        "color":"#fff"
                    },
                    "particles":{
                        "color":{
                            "value":"#000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name":"dark",
                "default":{
                    "value":true,
                    "mode":"dark"
                },
                "options":{
                    "background":{
                        "color":"#000"
                    },
                    "particles":{
                        "color":{
                            "value":"#fff"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The theme object accept those values, the options inside are a whole options so you can override everything from the background to the particles options.

Answer (score 1):

In the [GitHub reop](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/#usage) you can find the following example:

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

I guess that you can probably call this `load()` function with a new JSON file when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I've been trying and finally came to a solution. What I've done is to create a function associated to the theme selector checkbox.

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json');

function ThemeSwitch() {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox').value === 'dark') {
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles-light.json');
        document.getElementById('checkbox').value = 'light';
    } else {
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json');
        document.getElementById('checkbox').value = 'dark';
    }
}
```

And this is the input.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="check" value="dark" onclick="ThemeSwitch()"/>
```

Good or bad (have no JS idea pretty much), it is working.